# How to preserve state for component added to an favourite list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, themoviedb-api

I try to preserve state in three global views.

I have component `MovieRow` which is called in the `Popular`, Favorite and `Search` components. The goal is that component `MovieRow` preserve its state when it is called in this views (`Popular` ...)

For example, if I have 2 movies I checked one movie to add to favorite this movie should keep state. Now if I add a movie to the favorite list when I click and change the global view the component `MovieRow` will mount again and resets the state.

I tried many different ways. Store state one global variable with conditional render to my `MovieRow` and other.

Edit: You could see full code here https://codesandbox.io/s/lpjp0oxmmq

Edit 2 : I success store my state but I can't success to use correctly.

```
componentWillUnmount () {
    let storeState = localStorage.setItem('someSavedState', JSON.stringify(this.state))
    console.log(" ------------------- unmount ------------------- ")
    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someSavedState')))
    console.log(" ------------------- ------- ------------------- ")
}

componentWillMount() {
    const rehydrate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('someSavedState'))
    console.log(" ------------------- will mount ------------------- ")
    console.log(rehydrate)
    console.log(" ------------------- ---- ----- ------------------- ")
    // this.setState({isFaved: rehydrate})
}
```

Have you idea who help me ?

We see the state get lost in this picture. The color of the button who depend on the state has been reset.

[View popular with the first movie added to fav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Nuk.jpg)

[view favorite with fav movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZlqR.png)

MoviesRow.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import '../css/MovieRow.css';
import { APIKEY, baseURL } from '../../App'
import { filter } from '../../View/Popular'

var myFavoriteMovies = []

function IsFav(props) {
    return (
        <div movieId={props.movie.id} className="MovieRow">
        <div>
        <img alt="poster" src={props.posterSrc} />
        </div>
        <div>
        <h3>{props.movie.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.movie.overview}</p>
        <input type="button" value="View"/>

        <button onClick={props.onClick}  className=" heart">
        </button>

        </div>
        </div>
        );
}

function IsNotFav(props) {
    return (
        <div movieId={props.movie.id} className="MovieRow">
        <div>
        <img alt="poster" src={props.posterSrc} />
        </div>
        <div>
        <h3>{props.movie.title}</h3>
        <p>{props.movie.overview}</p>
        <input type="button" value="View"/>

        <button onClick={props.onClick} className="toggled heart">
        </button>

        </div>
        </div>

        );
}

class MovieRow extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.addFavorite = this.addFavorite.bind(this)
        this.deleteFavorite = this.deleteFavorite.bind(this)
        this.state = {
            isFaved: false,
        }
    }

    viewMovie() {
        const url = "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/" + this.props.movie.id
        window.location.href = url
        console.log(this.props.movie.id)
    }

    addFavorite() {
        this.setState({isFaved: true})
        const favMovie = "".concat(baseURL, 'movie/', this.props.movie.id ,'?api_key=', APIKEY) 
        myFavoriteMovies.push(favMovie)
    }

    deleteFavorite() {
        this.setState({isFaved: false})
    }

    render() {
        const isFaved = this.state.isFaved;
        let movie;

        if (isFaved) {
            movie = <IsNotFav  movie={this.props.movie} posterSrc={this.props.posterSrc} onClick={this.deleteFavorite}/>
        } else {
            movie = <IsFav movie={this.props.movie} posterSrc={this.props.posterSrc} onClick={this.addFavorite}/>
        }

        return movie
    }
}
export { MovieRow as default, myFavoriteMovies}
```

Comment: You could try declaring the `myFavoriteMovies` array in `Favorite` and passing it to `MovieRow` as a prop. Of course you would then need to pass `toggleFavorite` (bound to `Favorite`) as a prop as well. By moving state upwards like this, you can guarantee that `Favorite` will be sensitive to the state change and rerender accordingly.

Comment: Yes but all of my views (I have three global component `Popular` `Search` `Favorite`) All of this components displayed movies with `MovieRow`. 
I must display the favourite state in all global component. 
If I do your idea I having state up to date in `Favorite` global component and not in other like `Search` or `Popular` or in future components

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reworked your original code to provide an example of how to preserve state in your `Popular` component while traversing routes.

Please see the link below. Happy coding.

[CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3y9zk9xxm)

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you @CesarNapoleonMejiaLeiva. I had a bad begin. I restart with brain wave of your code.